# Странное поведение keyframes

Tags: css, keyframes

Ситуация следующая, когда кубу нужно повернуться по оси Х (с -40deg на 40deg), он почему-то подпрыгивает , при этом в конце анимации я делаю обратное (с 40deg на -40deg) и кубик вращается нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина ! Код приведен ниже....

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 500px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 4em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  perspective: 10000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg);
}

.box11 {
  animation: rot11 12s linear infinite;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  color: white;
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(1em);
  background: linear-gradient(153deg, #e66465, #9198e5);
  animation: topUCol 24s linear infinite;
}

.right {
  transform: translateZ(1em);
  animation: rightUCol 24s linear infinite;
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
  background: linear-gradient(127deg, #c45a5b, #6f76b2);
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
  animation: bottomUCol 24s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rot11 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box box11'>
    <div class='left side '></div>
    <div class='right side'></div>
    <div class='top side'></div>
    <div class='bottom side'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: backface-visibility: hidden попробуйте для блока к которому применяется анимация.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 500px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 4em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  perspective: 10000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg);
}

.box11 {
  animation: rot11 12s linear infinite;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  color: white;
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(1em);
  background: linear-gradient(153deg, #e66465, #9198e5);
  animation: topUCol 24s linear infinite;
}

.right {
  transform: translateZ(1em);
  animation: rightUCol 24s linear infinite;
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
  background: linear-gradient(127deg, #c45a5b, #6f76b2);
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
  animation: bottomUCol 24s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rot11 {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg);
  }
  29%,
  30% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  89% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box box11'>
    <div class='left side '></div>
    <div class='right side'></div>
    <div class='top side'></div>
    <div class='bottom side'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```